# Spring JMS Configuration using JNDI

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jndi, spring-jms

I am trying to load queue connection factory configurations using JNDI into My application which works fine when we use Queue Manager(IBM Websphere MQ) which is not secured. But when we changed to secured Queue Manager the same JNDI look up does not work. I am adding the logic used for JNDI look up below.

```
public class EpsJmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("jms/NotificationCF");
        bean.setResourceRef(false);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return (ConnectionFactory) connectionFactoryBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean epsXiBillPayNotificationDestinationBean() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("jms/epsXiBillPayNotificationQ");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Destination epsXiBillPayNotificationDestination() {
        return (Destination) epsXiBillPayNotificationDestinationBean().getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xiBillpayNotificationJmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate xiBillpayNotificationJmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(epsXiBillPayNotificationDestination());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the Queue Manager secured?  Does this mean you need to pass a username and password or does it require a client certificate on a TLS channel?